# Can't make SQL Server connection C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server on a local machine, run a SQL command against it and log the results. The code keeps failing at making the connection to the server.

I can't quite see what I'm doing wrong. Everything I've searched for either doesn't apply to this method or seems to match what I'm doing. I think I have other problems in the code as well, but I can't even get past the SQL connection to test the rest. Here is my code:

```
string svrConnection = "Server=.\\sqlexpress;Database="+db+";User ID=user;Password=password;";

SqlConnection con;
SqlCommand cmd;

Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\"db"\\");
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\\script.sql");

string PCS = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
con = new SqlConnection(svrConnection);

StreamWriter PCSLog = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\" + db + "\\Log" + db + ".txt");

try
{
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(PCS, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    using (SqlDataReader pcsrdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        using (PCSLog)
        {
            while (pcsrdr.Read())
                PCSLog.WriteLine(pcsrdr[0].ToString() + pcsrdr[1].ToString() + ",");
        }

    PCSLog.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection !", ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: What does ex.Message tell you?

Comment: Incorrect Syntax near "GO"  I thought if it was using 'ExecuteNonQuery();' it would read GO commands properly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We want to help you, but you should provide the necessary information. So please add the exception and the line which raised it to your question.

Comment: Then I think you are connecting to the database successfully and there is something wrong with the script you are trying to execute.

Comment: I've executed this script manually, hundreds of times without an issue.

Comment: @JOe ensure taht `GO` is on separate line.

Comment: There is another issue, though - you call `ExecuteNonQuery()` followed by `ExecuteReader` - that is not correct - `ExecuteNonQuery()` is for sql that does NOT return a result set.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide us with the commands that are in your script.sql file because it appears there is also some dependency to commands in that file that may be part of the issue here.

Comment: Also - you may have executed the script many times 'manually' but that is not a guarantee that it is well formed in this context.  Perhaps try separating your sql with `;`

Comment: It looks like part of the problem was the GO command.  It wasn't necessary since I didn't really need to break up batches, so I removed it.  I received a Timeout Expired ex.message now.

Comment: ok - that is easy enough to fix - you must have an expensive operation in your script - you can set the `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` higher (or even none=0)  if you want

Comment: Just a FYI, you might want to try using [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of doing `"...;Initial Catalog=" + db + ";..."` It will automatically do proper escaping in case the user does something stupid like put a `;` in the db name. In similar fashion you can use [`Path.Combine(`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) to build up your `"C:\\" + db + "\\Log" + db + ".txt"` reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is your connection string. Try this:

```
string svrConnection = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=" + db + ";User Id=user;Password=password;"
```

Or to get a connection using your windows credentials:

```
string svrConnection = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=" + db + ";Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

Also, ExecuteNonQuery does not run each command separated by GO. You will need to split your query into sections and run each individually.

Comment: The issue is not with the connection string - it is with the script - your last comment is the answer

Answer (score 2):

There are additional problems with your code:

- The Lines
  cmd.Dispose();
  con.Close();
  are not guaranteed to execute if an exception occurs.
- You call `PCSLog.Close` AFTER after you have disposed of it

I would suggest this as a better alternative (irrespective of the other comments made here).

```
string svrConnection = "Server=.\\sqlexpress;Database="+db+";User ID=user;Password=password;"; 
Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\" + db + "\\");
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\\script.sql");
string PCS = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

try
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(svrConnection))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(PCS, con))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            using (SqlDataReader pcsrdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            using (StreamWriter PCSLog = new StreamWriter("C:\\" + db + "\\Log" + db + ".txt"))
            {
                while (pcsrdr.Read())
                    PCSLog.WriteLine(pcsrdr[0].ToString() + pcsrdr[1].ToString() + ","); 
            }

        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection !", ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Don't need `PCSLog.Close();` either as it's dealt with as part of the `using (StreamWriter PCSLog = ...` line.